# Nautilus file notes (user metadata) workaround: how to display note in popup?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, python

This post gives a python program for adding and viewing notes on files under Nautilus: 
[File notes tab gone in Nautilus 3.2.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90853/file-notes-tab-gone-in-nautilus-3-2-1)

It works!

I want more....

The annotated file does not have any indication in the file list (the icon does not have the traditional note attached). Hovering or right click does not display the note; notes only display if you run the annotator python program (but you don't know whether the file you are looking at is annotated or not, and it is not quick to run the annotator python program.)

In short, I would like a filelist column with annotations....

Can I tell Nautilus to automatically check for an annotation and change the icon (though I might prefer a column with the annotation)?